# How to define curry in Lean

Tags: lean, beginner, lean3

I just started with Lean and with this nice SE.

In the official web book/tutorial, when explaining definitions https://leanprover.github.io/theorem_proving_in_lean/index.html they ask to complete this (partial) definition of curry (in paragraph 2.4):

```
def curry (α β γ : Type*) (f : α × β → γ) : α → β → γ := sorry
```

I tried

```
def curry (α β γ : Type*) (f : α × β → γ) : α → β → γ := λ  x y, f (x,y)
```

and it seems to be accepted by the system.

Is this definition correct? If yes, how do I use it?

I expected something like

`curry x y f`    or      `curry f x y`

should work, but they don't.

Actually the given (partial) definition is of type `α → β → γ` so it expects just 2 arguments of type α and `β` respectively, but no function `f`.

Thank you for your help

Comment: @GuyCoder yes I use lean3

Comment: thanks for the edit

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If Lean checks your code you know it is correct.  (Well, that and the fact there is only one curry function up to functional equivalence.)

Now as for how to use `curry` you just defined, notice the type signature says you need to put in the following things in order:

- `α : Type*`
- `β : Type*`
- `γ : Type*`
- `f : α × β → γ`
- `x : α`
- `y : β`

So you have to use it as, e.g.

```
curry ℕ bool ℤ f n b
```

---

Note, it is cumbersome to have to write the types since you can usually get them from the types of `f`, `n`, and `b` in this case.  So usually (and [the tutorial will get to this soon](https://leanprover.github.io/theorem_proving_in_lean/dependent_type_theory.html#implicit-arguments)), you write this function using curly braces for the arguments which are implicit:

```
def curry' {α β γ : Type*} (f : α × β → γ) : α → β → γ := λ  x y, f (x,y)
```

In this case, you can write this as

```
curry' f x y
```

or in rare cases when you need to supply the types:

```
@curry' α β γ f x y
```

Comment: thank you Jason, all is clear now. I misunderstood the syntax of def